# How do I get the account_index parameter for the wallet RPC?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

I am using the Monero wallet RPC method [get_balance](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#get_balance) to get my wallet balance. 
One of the inputs is `account_index`, which is described as:

> account_index - unsigned int; Return balance for this account.

What is `account_index` and how do I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every wallet has a main account at index 0. If you created other accounts in the wallet, they also have an index, as shown in the wallet. Using [get_balance](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#get_balance), you can even omit the field `account_index` as it will default to the main account (index 0).